# The webpage closes after some time in IE because of some memory leaks in this code

Tags: javascript, ajax, memory-leaks

There are probably memory leaks in this code  because some people get sudden browser crash (most likely that they have IE) when the page stays open for a while. The code is intended to replace text inside "info" tags with new version of it in order for people not to reload page manually. I inspected the page behavior with IE development tools and there is increase in number of objects but not very big (20 kB per day). Can you help me detect the memory problem or maybe it is something else?

```
//reload partially page with ajax (only new content between <info> tags)
var HTTP = {};
HTTP._factories = [function () {
        return new XMLHttpRequest();
    }, function () {
        return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }, function () {
        return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
];
HTTP._factory = null;
HTTP.newRequest = function () {
    if (HTTP._factory != null)
        return HTTP._factory();
    for (var i = 0; i < HTTP._factories.length; i++) {
        try {
            var factory = HTTP._factories[i];
            var request = factory();
            if (request != null) {
                HTTP._factory = factory;
                return request;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    HTTP._factory = function () {
        throw new Error("This browser doesn't permit automatic reload of content");
    }
    HTTP._factory();
}
//reloads contents inside of <info> tags every minute 
function reloadInfo() {
    var request = HTTP.newRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
            if (request.status == 200)
                var infodoc = request.responseText;
            var infodiv = infodoc.substring(infodoc.indexOf('<info>'), infodoc.indexOf('</info>') + 7);
            document.getElementById('info').parentNode.innerHTML = infodiv;
        }
    }
    request.open("GET", window.location);
    request.send(null);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var interval = 60000;
    setInterval("reloadInfo()", interval);
}
```